# Contentful GraphQL filter for filtering entries by linked references

Tags: content-management-system, contentful, contentful-management, contentful-api

I read this blog post which shows how to filter entries by linked references in contentful Graphql.
https://www.contentful.com/blog/2021/06/15/filter-entries-by-linked-references-in-graphql-api/
But i can't do as it says. Graphql playground only highlighting the entryCollection with sys data. I need the parent blogPostCollection but it doesn't show up. What should I do ? Anything changed ? I followed all the tutorials and blog but it ain't working anymore.
Besides I can't query the author-name and details under the blogPostCollection. It's already took a lot of time. I tried the same schema in sanity and I was able to query the author details under the blog post.
[image]

Comment: did you find a solution to this? I have exactly the same problem.

Comment: No, I've started using Sanity IO. Everything works perfectly, no issues. and well documented.